# VB.NET MySQL : Error 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have trouble with my coding below :

```
Private Function NoCustID() As String
        Dim drtmp As MySqlDataReader
        Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sTmp As String
        Dim nStr As String

    dbConn.Open()
    sTmp = "SELECT * FROM tbnomor WHERE ftipe=1 AND UPPER(fnama)='CUSTOMER'"
    mySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(sTmp, dbConn)
    drtmp = mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()

    nStr = drtmp("fprefix").ToString & "-" & String.Format(drtmp("ftempno").ToString, "0000")
    dbConn.Close()
    Return nStr
End Function
```

Error raised on Line With ExecuteScalar(), where the error code as shown above title.
I don't know what mistake.
Please help, thanks

Comment: IMHO, do all of this in the db and return it the way you need to.

Comment: `mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns `null` , `db null` or CLR `dataType`. But you assign this type to `drtmp = ` defied as `Dim drtmp As MySqlDataReader`

Comment: You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the VS options, so it is `On` by default in future projects. That code would refuse to compile in that case and warn you that there's a problem. Having `Option Strict Off` let's you play fast and loose with data types and, while the system often cleans up the mess, it can't always do. that can lead to crashes or, even worse, the app may carry on silently while using the wrong data. Having `Option Strict On` will make you write better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't declare connections outside of the method where they are used. Both connections and commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`

`.ExecuteScalar` is used to return a single piece of data. You need `.ExecuteReader` to return a `DataReader`.

Don't process data until the connection is closed with `End Using`.

I filled a `DataTable` so your could process the data after the connection is closed. Readers require an open connection.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function NoCustID() As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using dbConn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbnomor WHERE ftipe=1 AND UPPER(fnama)='CUSTOMER'", dbConn)
        dbConn.Open()
        Using drtmp = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(drtmp)
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim nStr = $"{dt(0)("fprefix")} -  {dt(0)("ftempno"):0000}"
    Return nStr
End Function
```

Comment: not just answer i got, but also a thoughtful of code for me to learn..kudosssss

Answer (score 1):

Change `drtmp = mySqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` to `drtmp = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader()`.
The method `ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row in the result and ignore others. In this instance, the returned column is integer data type, and not an array.

Use:

```
drtmp = mySqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
While drtmp.Read()
        nStr = drtmp("fprefix").ToString & "-" & String.Format(drtmp("ftempno").ToString, "0000")
End While
```

Comment: if its a single record, wouldn't it be "if" rather than while?

Comment: Either works. The Read() method returns Boolean that "while" or "if" evaluates before executing the enclosed block of code(s), when true.